# Reverse Geocode using OSM to get nearest node/ way information

Tags: matlab, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

I am very new to geocode and quite overwhelmed with all the information. I have seen similar questions to the one I have but I haven't been able to figure out the solution. I hope you'll can help.

I have a .csv file that is populated with over thousand coordinates (Lat, Long, Alt).

I want to be able process the coordinates on an Open Source service (OSM) to be able to understand on what type of street the vehicle is.

Eg. (53.0066,-2.0031) scanned though OSM database to find nearest mapped coordinate:

```
<node id="781098178" visible="true" version="2" changeset="11563939" timestamp="2012-05-11T00:04:35Z" user="Mauls" uid="24119" lat="53.0002499" lon="-2.0056501"/>
```

which is then tagged as `<tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>`

It is the highway and bus_stop information I am interested in as the output.

I have read and had a go with the MapQuest API's available but I am unable to make the reverse geocode display the tag information rather than the whole address. Also I'm not sure how to make the matlab script work.

I really hope you'll can help. Sorry if I have sounded stupid!

Thank you ever so much....

Comment: Just offer us your code, so we can help

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! +1, hard to help with your code without seeing it. if you can post a minimal, relevant piece of code, you will get better answers.

Comment: You might find better luck on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two steps for this.

The first step is doing a reverse geocoding call to [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), OSM's most popular geocoding service. Be aware that OSM's official Nominatim instance has a rather strict [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy) because it runs on funded servers. But you can use [MapQuest's Nominatim instance](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim) as an alternative and even [install your own instance](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). Because Nominatim only stores the post-processed data it doesn't have any information about the original tags.

The second step is extracting the `osm_type` (which is the type of the [element](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and can be either `node`, `way` or `relation`) and the `osm_id` (which uniquely identifies the element) from Nominatim's result. With these information you have to make a call to the [OSM API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Read%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2F.5Bnode.7Cway.7Crelation.5D.2F.23id) to get all information about the corresponding element. This includes all tags.

Note that there is a similar [Question&Answer platform for OSM](https://help.openstreetmap.org/) which allows you to reach a much larger part of the OSM community.

Comment: thank you for responding with this. Really helpful. I have looked into the MapQuest api part and tried to implement it in my matlab code but it just wouldn't work....not sure what's going on. Could you have a look at the edited question please.

Comment: No I can't. I don't know Matlab and I won't help you on Google questions, sorry. And your edited question has absolutely nothing to do with the original one. I suggest reverting the edit, accepting my answer and starting a new question for your new code.